How to get suspend to also save to disk in Ubuntu 24.04 noble
In systemd/sleep.conf, the setting 'SuspendState=disk' does not work anymore.
It worked on previous versions (23.10 22.04).
If I do set it I get:
$ sudo systemctl suspend
Call to Suspend failed: Sleep verb 'suspend' is not configured or configuration is not supported by kernel
exit code: 1

In the docs, it shows that other settings like HybridSleepState and HibernateState were cancelled. But it doesn't tell any change about SuspendState.
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/man5/systemd-sleep.conf.5.html
I have been using this setting 'SuspendState=disk' since 22.04 (or maybe earlier), to make my suspend operation safer. That is, if the electricity goes off at some point later, the machine can recover like from hibernate.
This describes "Hybrid-Sleep", that is, in practice I want all my suspend operations to do Hybrid-Sleep, whether invoked by user or by automatic sleep like:
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'
gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'

### note that these settings do not have a hybrid-sleep option !!!

Other info:
$ cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem disk


Where did you read that modes like hybrid-sleep etc. were "cancelled"? The manual page you linked describes them all and when they have been added, but not that those modes were removed.

@cyberbrain I did not say "modes" were cancelled. I said the settings HibernateState and HybridSleepState were.
They don't appear in the list anymore since 24.04. As well as SuspendMode and HybridSleepMode.
The ones that remain are SuspendState and HibernateMode.
